# Uninterupted Printing Of Int Array Using Write System Call

Tags: c, arrays, system-calls

My main program is creating multiple children that are each writing to stdout. In order to avoid them writing over each other, I'm using a sprintf write combo, like so:

```
sprintf(buf, "Bubble Sort Process Started\n");
write(0, &buf, strlen(buf));
```

When I try to print out an int array I run into a problem. The size of the array changes each time the program runs, so I can't have one set sprintf to print everything at once. The only other way I can think to print it is iterating through the array using a loop, but then other processes can have their output appear part way through. How can I get the entire array to print without having another process print its output at the same time?

Comment: BTW,  I think you should be writing to fd 1 rather than fd 0.

Comment: Is `buf` an array or a pointer? In any case, the second parameter of `write` should be `buf`, not `&buf`. But if `buf` is a pointer then the call to `write` will write the pointer value, not the buffer contents. Also, file descriptor 0 is usually _standard input_, not _standard output_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on a POSIX system (as you probably are, judging from your assumption that there's a `write` system call), you should be able to set a lock to filedescriptor 1 before your start your write calls,  and unlock it after you're done with your `write` batch.

Below is a simple program that demonstrates it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void print(char C)
{
    for(;;){
#if LOCK
        fcntl(1, F_SETLKW, &(struct flock){ F_WRLCK, SEEK_SET, 0, 1 });
#endif
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            write(1, &C, 1);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
#if LOCK
        fcntl(1, F_SETLKW, &(struct flock){ F_UNLCK, SEEK_SET, 0, 1 });
#endif
    }
}
int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) /*4 children*/
        if(0==fork())
            print('a'+i);
    pause(); /*terminate it with Ctrl+C*/

}
```

This program will create 4 children, each attempting to print an infinite series of lines, where each line consists of 100 characters C ('a' for the first child, 'b' for the second, etc.). Since the writes are made 1 byte at a time, the lines will be intertwined. Compile with -DLOCK=1, and each outputted line will be uninterrupted.